# jquery Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token - Input text has an apostrophe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp

I have the current problem regarding an input which I use for searching a vast variety of articles.
To get more in depth, the thing is that when I insert a text with an apostrophe, I get the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

```
  function set_id_article_popover(id, name){
   $('#articles_search_input').val(id);
   $('#articles_search_popover').val(name);
   $('#articles_search_popover').blur();
   $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
    $(this).popover('hide');
  });
```

`$('#articles_search_popover').val(name);` is where I insert article's name.
 `$('#articles_search_input').val(id);` gets the id of the article to search.
First number is inserted correctly inside the function, which is the id of the article `set_id_article_popover(id, name)`

```
          <div class="item" id="articles_search_popover_container">
              <i class="fa fa-newspaper-o placeholder_input_icotext-muted_light"></i>
                    <input name='name_busqueda' 
                        autocomplete ='off' <?php if(!empty($value1)) 
                           {echo 'value="'.$value1.'"';} ?> type="text" 
                           data-texts='1' 
                           data-toggle="popover" 
                           title="<i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle'></i>&nbsp;<span class='text-muted'><?php echo __('Busca por especialidad o tratamiento');?></span>" data-lang="<?php echo $this->params['language'];?>" 
                            data-search="articles" 
                            id="articles_search_popover" 
                            data-lang="<?php echo $lang; ?>"
                            class="form-control" 
                            placeholder="<?php echo __('Buscar en artículos');?>">
                             <!-- Popover "Especialidad / Especialista" -->
                           <?php echo $this->element(
                            '/main_search/custom_autocomplete', 
                            array(
                             'id' => 'articles_search_popover', 
                             'headers' => false,
                             'specialties' => true,
                            'specialist'=> false,
                            'top_specialties' => false,
                            'treatments' => true,
                            'cols' => '1')
                            ); ?>
      </div>
```

Now, I will attach you the part of the Controller to have a better grasp of what is happening in the back-end.

```
  if(isset($this->request->query['name_busqueda']) 
   && $this->request->query['name_busqueda'] != ""){
      $word = $this->request->query['name_busqueda'];
   }

    if(isset($word) && $word != "" && !strpos($word, "-")){
        $words_titulo = $word;
    }

    if(isset($articles_search) && $articles_search != ""){
        $word_search = false;
        //specialty or treatment is selected
        $data = $this->request->query['articles_search'];
        $data = explode("_",$data);
        $tipo = $data[0];

        if($tipo === 'specialty'){
            //search by specalty
            $specialty_id = $data[1];//id

            if(!empty($this->params['language']) && $this->params['language'] != 'es'){
                $name_field_sufix = '_' . $this->params['language'];
            } else {
                $name_field_sufix = '';
            }

            $specialty = $this->Specialization->find('first', array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'name' . $name_field_sufix .' AS name'
                ),
                'conditions' => array(
                    'id' => $specialty_id
                )
            ));

            if(!empty($specialty)) {
                $words_titulo = $specialty['Specialization']['name'];
            }


            $options['conditions'] = array(
                'ArticlesSpec.specialization_id' => $specialty_id
            );
            $this->set('specialty_id', $specialty_id);

        }else{

            //search by treatment
            $treatment_id = $data[1];//id

            if(!empty($this->params['language']) && $this->params['language'] != 'es'){
                $name_field_sufix = '_' . $this->params['language'];
            } else {
                $name_field_sufix = '';
            }

            $treatment = $this->Treatment->find('first', array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'name' . $name_field_sufix .' AS name'
                ),
                'conditions' => array(
                    'id' => $treatment_id
                )
            ));

            $aux_join = array(
                array(
                    'table' => 'td_articles_treatments',
                    'alias' => 'ArticlesTreat',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'ArticlesTreat.article_id = Article.id',
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'table' => 'td_treatments',
                    'alias' => 'Treatments',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'ArticlesTreat.treatment_id = Treatments.id',
                    ),
                )
            );

            $options['joins'] = array_merge($joins, $aux_join);
            $campos_aux = ', ArticlesTreat.*, Treatments.*';
            $options['conditions'] = array('ArticlesTreat.treatment_id' => $treatment_id);

            if(!empty($treatment)) {
                $words_titulo = $treatment['Treatment']['name'];
            }

        }

    }
```

Do you know if there is a possibility of transforming the apostrophe through Cake or would it be better to do it through Javascript ?

I tried applying some solutions by replacing the apostrophe with an escape plus an alternative encoding character so that the input would be read more concisely, but I am kind of at a dead-end here. Any help would be quite appreciated.
I am attaching you a couple of screen captures so I can guide you precisely of what is happening.

[image]
On this first one, I start to write on the search input.
I fill it up with whichever info I want to.

[image]
On this second one, when I do the search and I click the button, it spits out the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`
This is what happens in my development server.

Thanks

Comment: where specifically is that error being generated? Just by typing an apostrophe into the input box wouldn't cause the error - the error is being spit out by JS cause it's got some bad data, it's specifically being generated when you are trying to parse JSON, which, unless you are doing it else where, would be either in the call or the response.  So is the call failing before it is actually sent, or is the data being returned unable to be parsed?  This will help figure out where to put or fix in.

Comment: Check my edited answer.

Comment: It is still occurring and I am seeing the same error while I am trying to set the item and its respective id for the search. Whenever there is an apostrophe, it displays the same thing. I tried checking the back-end but it is not something that has to do with it. It is something that has to do clearly with the server-side part. I delved into other posts of how single quote or apostrophe affect JSON and the only answer I could manage to find was to replace the single quote or apostrophe with an escape charater. By all means, I tried testing it to my development server, and still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem finally after a long time.
In the line where the function is being called on the onclick event inside this view, I had applied a json_encode function with PHP upon the name and therefore I was able to solve and do the query. 
That way the value's name I was searching for is being returned with json and there is no need of escaping the single quote character or doing other superfluous conversions.

```
  <section class="item list-group-item">
            <input type="hidden" id="treat_id" value="treatment_<?php echo $id;?>">
            <input type="hidden" id="treat_name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
            <a onclick='set_id_article_popover("treatment_<?php echo $id;?>",  <?php echo json_encode($final_name); ?>)' class="center-block thumb_xxs">
                <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
                <?php 
                if(strlen($name) > 50){
                    $name_short= substr($name, 0, 50).' ...';
                }else{
                    $name_short = $name;
                }
                $bname = returnBold($name_short, $search_text);
                ?>
                <span title="<?php echo $name ?>" class="text-muted"><?php echo $bname; ?></span>
            </a>
        </section>
```